# library not found for -lPods from GitHub project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am getting the following error when trying to build a project I found on GitHub.

```
ld: library not found for -lPod 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've heard of some people saying to use the workspace file instead of the workspace file but there is no project file.

Here is the [project](https://github.com/pablosproject/iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV)

Comment: normally i got this error while using cocoa pods for dependency(after opening workspace). my trick to solve this is to select all target in Pods-->target -->architecture ->standard architecture(including 64 bit).

Comment: Have you installed the required Cocoapods for the project? Is there a Podfile?

Comment: I have not done anything besides download it and attempt to run it. I do not see a podfile but I see some .h and .m that have pod in their name and Pods.xcodeproj.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the link to the project. There *is* a Podfile in the top level of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project uses Cocoapods to manage its third party dependencies. Whilst the developer has committed the `Pods/` directory, it's probably best to install the Pods yourself:

1. [Install Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/#install) if you don't already have it: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
2. `cd` into the top level project directory, and install the required Pods for this project: `pod install`
3. Open the `TestOCR.xcworkspace` that will be created.
4. Build and run.

Answer (score 2):

My app can run on simulator but can't run on device.

I fixed this by these steps.

1. The Pods Xcode project now sets the ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH build setting to YES in the Debug configuration. You will have to set the same on your project/target, otherwise the build will fail.
2. Ensure your project/target has an ARCHS value set, otherwise the build will fail.
3. When building a iOS project from the command-line, with the xcodebuild tool that comes with Xcode 4, you’ll need to completely disable this setting by appending to your build command: ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO.

http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html

All my pods project have debug build only active architecture to YES(from pod install), but my project set to NO. So, I change it to YES, then it's work.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, all I had to do was simply drag the Pods.xcodeproj into the TestOCR.xcodeproj thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue couple of times and the common fix is to simply build the Pods target.

The project seems to have bad CocoaPods configuration (or not at all). There is no workspace and no Podfile (which is even worse, because if there's a Podfile you can install CocoaPods by your own and update pods).

You can look into Pods directory and try to create Podfile from scratch (depending on found libraries) and the install CocoaPods. This should work.

Comment: I found that selecting "Find implicit Dependencies" (under product / edit scheme) will resolve this issue instead of having to add pods as a target.